# Error: Cannot find module 'number-is-nan'

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I am building a react native app using expo-cli. I was in the middle of testing out two UI buttons that send redux actions to reducers to update a UI date label. I got that working and what seems out of no where when I run 'expo start' in the terminal I get this error. I've tried running 'npm install' because it seemed like it was saying I am missing a module but the error persists.

```
[23:05:46] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
[23:05:46]     throw err;
[23:05:46]     ^
[23:05:46] 
[23:05:46] Error: Cannot find module 'number-is-nan'
[23:05:46]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
[23:05:46]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
[23:05:46]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
[23:05:46]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[23:05:46]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sasheem/Desktop/dev/react-native/[projectName]-tiptracker/node_modules/is-finite/index.js:2:19)
[23:05:46]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
[23:05:46]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
[23:05:46]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
[23:05:46]     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
[23:05:46]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
[23:05:46] Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
[23:05:46] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

It doesn't really point to any recent code that I have added and I don't recognize using any of the folders it is showing in the error message.

Right before this error message it tells me to update my expo-cli but when I run 'npm install -g expo-cli' and check to see if it actually updated with 'expo-cli --version' it still tells me I am running the old version (2.2.0)

```
There is a new version of expo-cli available (2.6.14).
You are currently using expo-cli 2.2.0
Run `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version
```

Let me know if there is anymore information I can provide to help solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added this package `number-is-nan` to your `package.json`

Or if it is not added, simply run `npm install --save number-is-nan`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I never touch my package.json so I don't get why it was missing all of a sudden.